# Xcode: How do I "scroll" the table view in designer when designing static cells, to reach cells off screen?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, designer

Probably the silliest question you've seen today, but I can't figure out how I can reach the off-screen cells, so i can customize them (In the designer)

How can I customize the 4th cell in section 2 (or anything below, not visible):

[image: Valid XHTML]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply select the table view and then scroll using a scroll wheel or touchpad.

Comment: Dear god, i knew it was a silly question. In my defense, I already tried that, but it didn't react. Turns out i just had to scroll more than just a little before it started moving. I'm using a PC mouse, maybe that's why it didn't react immediately. Thanks anyway!